# Best way to track database table/column for html form control

Tags: php, javascript, data-mapping

I am working on a php program that requires javascript on every form control. Once the onblur event takes place the value will automatically be sent to the server to update the database.

I have possibly 50 form controls spread over 5 tabs so I don't want to hardcode the information on the php file.

I could co-opt an idea from [HTML5](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/) and create new properties for this such as

```
data-table='user' data-column='firstname'
```

for every item, and then javascript could pull those values out and send them to the php file.

I don't know if there is a better way to manage the mapping between these form controls and the several tables/columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML

```
<input id='data-base*data-colum' onblur='preupdate(this);' value='' />
```

Javascript

```
function preupdate(el){
   var idData = el.getAttribute('id').split('*');
   var dataBase = idData[0];
   var dataColum = idData[1];

   update(el.value, dataBase, dataColum);
}
```

Comment: I like this idea of using the id field. I didn't think about putting both the table and column in it. The simplicity is great. Thank you.

Comment: I have implemented this for the updates and inserts and though I had to make some changes, encoding where columns and values, it worked out very well.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I think that's the best option you have. If you use jquery, you can do something like this :

```
$("input").blur(function () {
    var data-table = $(this).attr('data-table');
    var data-column = $(this).attr('data-column');

    $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: your_url,
    data: your_get_data
    });
});
```

Comment: I was hoping for a better solution, as it seems like the best option to me, but, it is nice to sometimes see if I am missing something. Thanx for the response. <g>

Comment: Oh, one thing, I would not send this as a GET request, mainly because each GET request tends to be stored in a log file, but POST isn't, and no point filling up log files needlessly.  I limit get requests a great deal, to where it makes sense.

Comment: Yeah, I forgott to change the get to post actually, you're right.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use PHP to generate a data structure mapping the controls (hopefully they have unique names/ids) to the db info. Then I'd spit this out in JSON as inline javascript in .

Then your `on_blur` attributes on all your fields can be the same (or each pass a unique id for that field) and call a javascript function that looks up the db info from the data structure.

Comment: This could be a nice solution for small databases, but if it begins to get large then it can start to be difficult to send the data back and forth, but, for a small amount of data this may be a good solution. Thank you.

Comment: Huh? Maybe you don't understand what I suggested. I'm thinking of having php generate a string like this: "field_meta = ['email': ['accounts','email'], 'description': ['profile','text']];" and put that in a <script> tag. Then your javascript can get the table like so field_meta[field_name][0] and the column like so: field_meta[field_name][1]. So we're talking probably 20-50 characters per field, all easily accessible as a hash.

Comment: Did you think I meant to pass the entire structure of your entire database perhaps? I was thinking of just passing the table/column data for the fields that are actually on the form.